# Jquery include is breaking console.log?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, console

I have a simple page that does a console.log:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Chess</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="js/jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js">
<script>
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="maincanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black;">
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

All I have to do is remove the jquery include and the console.log shows up in the chrome web developer tools console. I'm confused, what is jquery doing to console.log?

Comment: any error on the console?

Comment: the other guys are right, you didn't close your script tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script tags are not self-closing tags. Please refer to the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

You need to change the script tag to close:

`<script src="js/jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: That fixed it. Note that using <script src="..."/> doesn't work either.

Comment: Well, yes, because they're not void elements. Refer to the answer to this question for the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/2748503

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
<script src="js/jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js">
```

is missing a closing `</script>` tag.